# How can I select data from a Tensorflow Dataset data collection?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

Is there any way to select features or labels from a tensorflow Dataset without using numpy conversion methods or iterate through?

The simplest example I found is:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
print(ds)
>> <_OptionsDataset shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>
```

In this case, `_OptionsDataset` holds data in a `dict`, but the collection can be a `tuple`, `list` or even a `np.ndarray`.

---

If there is not a way to select data directly from a tensorflow Dataset, what's the most commonly used alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ds.map()` function to create dataset conatains only images or labels:

```
ds_images = ds.map(lambda d:d['images')
```

the original purpose of the `map` function is manipulating the data without converting to numpy, for example:

```
ds_images = ds.map(lambda d:d['images']/255)
```

hope I helped you.